No rows are showing up in my SQLite database table
At this online browser and another one I used the following statements didn't show any rows after inserting into the table:
CREATE TABLE "non_strict_table" ("name" TEXT PRIMARY KEY, "data" BLOB);
INSERT INTO "non_strict_table" ("name", "data") VALUES ('name_01', 'blob_data');

Is there something here? I know 'blob_data' is text and not blob, but it can be implicitly converted to blob, so is there something wrong with these statements? Why don't they show up as rows in the visualisation panel thingy?

Which "visualisation panel thingy"? You might have to refresh it. I like to work with SQLiteStudio.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes Oh OK, I downloaded DB Browser for SQLite, is SQLiteStudio better?

Did you execute SELECT * FROM non_strict_table to see the rows? The browser doesn't show them automatically.

Sorry, I don't know DB Browser for SQLite.

In SQL, implicit conversion from TEXT to BLOB doesn’t work in the way you're thinking. You need to provide binary data for the BLOB column explicitly.
INSERT INTO "non_strict_table" ("name", "data") VALUES ('name_01', CAST('blob_data' AS BLOB));

This converts the string 'blob_data' to a BLOB and stores it.

I thought it did implicit conversion. Like, I know if you give it a string and it has integer or numeric affinity it converts it if it can. It doesn't do implicit string to blob conversion?

Ohh I just the table. If you create a blob column it has no affinity.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_data_types.htm
